# SSRS - CASE Expression with Parameter in SELECT

Tags: plsql, ssrs-2008, parameter-passing, case, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report in Report Builder, SSRS.  I need to add a CASE with Parameter in the SELECT Statement (PL/SQL).

The parameters are: `@DateFrom`, `@DateTo`, `@Check`.

If I hardcode the value (without parameter values) the my query is fine.

But if I code like the below I got error 'End of Statement expected'.

```
SELECT
  ....,    
  CASE     
    WHEN ( (ExpiryDate BETWEEN '" & UCase(Format(Parameters!DateFrom.Value,"dd-MMM-yyyy")) &"' 
                       AND     '" & UCase(Format(Parameters!DateTo.Value,"dd-MMM-yyyy"))   &"' 
           )
            AND     Check IN ('" & Join(Parameters!Check.Value,"','") & "') 
         ) THEN 'Current' 
    WHEN ((ExpiryDate <= '" & UCase(Format(Parameters!DateFrom.Value,"dd-MMM-yyyy")) & "')  AND  Check = 'Y')  THEN 'Before'
    WHEN ((ExpiryDate >= '" & UCase(Format(Parameters!DateTo.Value,"dd-MMM-yyyy")) & "')    AND  Check = 'Y')  THEN 'After'     
   END as MyGroup,
  ...
FROM ...
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the parameters into the query with usual parameter syntax? For Oracle queries, this would be `...ExpiryDate BETWEEN :DateFrom AND :DateTo ) ...`

Comment: Hi Jamie.  Thank you very much for the quick response.   Yes, I did.  And I just found out the solution: it was not because of the CASE part above.. The problem was with something else in the statement.  Thank you kindly again :)